# What's the chemical formula of "Everitt's salt"?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, identification

According to my school textbook (which is notorious, for being in possession of several errors), a certain "Everitt's salt" is a complex that results from the reduction of Prussian Blue.

Everitt's salt (according to our inglorious textbook)  has the chemical formula $\ce{K2[Fe(CN)6]}$... which I straightaway dismissed as nonsense, because it would mean it's got $\ce{Fe^{4+}}$ (ferryl ion). From my (very limited) knowledge of the subject, the ferryl ion doesn't look like something that would occur in any reasonably stable compound; since Everitt's salt is, well, a "salt" (and since salts can usually be crystallized into stable solids).

Google wasn't much help in this regard,

> [image]
>
> <sub>I've no idea how to interpret the formula that is supposedly that of Everitt's salt</sub>

---

Questions:

1) Is there really something called "Everitt's salt"? Is it produced by the reduction of Prussian Blue?

2) What's its chemical formula?

Comment: Everitt's salt appears to be of mixed valence in iron: $\ce{K2Fe[Fe(CN)6]}$ http://www.molbase.com/en/cas-15362-86-4.html

Comment: @Gert Hmm... so Everitt's salt is a ferrous ferrocyanide salt? :O

Comment: acc. to that source, yes. Never before heard of it.

Comment: @Gert I'm no chemist (so that site doesn't impress upon me as strongly as chemspider or sigma aldrich), but would you want to make that an answer? O:)

Comment: no because I don't know whether it is produced by the reduction of Prussian Blue.

Comment: @Gert  [This Wiki section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_blue#Production) mentions that Prussian Blue can be created by the oxidation of the compound you mentioned; it doesn't call it "Everitt's salt" though :/ But it fits the bill (I think), since the ferrous ferrocyanide is a "reduced" form of Prussian Blue. :-)

Comment: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100323a055?journalCode=jpchax Yes it's made by reduction

Comment: @Mith Aha! Good find! Okay, so now there's a (fairly) reliable source that mentions Everitt's salt... but there's no mention of the formula. So I can't tell if what Gert found is the same thing :(

Comment: file:///C:/Users/User/Downloads/BHC39p18.pdf This source references the same formula for ES as my Molbase reference. Find the pdf here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281176633_On_the_History_of_Prussian_Blue_Thomas_Everitt_1805-1845_and_Everitts_Salt

Comment: @Gert Looks like that's settled then! (How about an answer now?) :D

Comment: @Mith Well, Gert seems to have nailed it. Consider posting an answer of your own too (referencing the document you linked), since you've confirmed that Everitt's salt is made by the reduction of PB; it'll  be a legitimate (albeit, not exactly complete) answer and will get my upvote O:)

Comment: There is an obvious typo in the image. Notice that there is a right bracket ] but no left bracket [. So the author made some kind of mistake.

Comment: **Update**: I have asked ["What is the chemical composition of Ferrous Ferrocyanide?"](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/157652/what-is-the-chemical-composition-of-ferrous-ferrocyanide)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to various sources Everitt's Salt has the formula $\ce{K2Fe[Fe(CN)6]}$, where both $\ce{Fe}$ are in the $+2$ Oxidation State. Everitt described it as a yellow precipitate, resulting from the reaction:

$$\ce{2 K4Fe(CN)6(aq) + 6 H2SO4(aq) \to 6 HCN(g) + 6 KHSO4(aq) + K2Fe[Fe(CN)6](s)}$$

Acc. Everitt, the wet salt can be oxidised to Prussian Blue by the action of air (oxygen).

[Source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281176633_On_the_History_of_Prussian_Blue_Thomas_Everitt_1805-1845_and_Everitts_Salt).